# SoundCloud disable autoplay

Tags: soundcloud

YouTube has the option to disable autoplay. However SoundCloud appears to have no such option. Is this the case or can it be disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now do this.

If you click "Next up", you will see an "Autoplay station" option.

[image: Illustration of how to disable autoplay on soundcloud]

1. Click, "Next up" which is a list icon on the bottom right of the screen.
2. Toggle, "Autoplay station" off in the Next up menu.

Comment: Here is a userscript which does this automatically: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/388427-soundcloud-disable-autoplay-station

Comment: It just seems to reset this to "on" status every time though.

Answer (score 0):

Update: That icon no longer appears.

Type q, scroll to the bottom, then toggle auto play off. I learned this by hitting the `...` icon in the upper right next to Upload. This brings up a menu. At the bottom of the menu hit the keyboard shortcuts. This brings up another long list in a window. At the bottom right of the list is a Bold Q with Show Up Next beside it.  Close the window and type q which brings up another very long window. Scroll to the bottom and toggle off Autoplay Station.